# Global keyword in Visual Basic 2005?

Tags: .net, vb.net, legacy-code

I have to inherit some legacy code in company, which is written in Visual Basic.NET 7.0 (Visual Studio.NET 2002). I don't have much experiences in VB.NET, and this line of code gets me in trouble:

```
Public Class Global : Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication
```

Visual Studio gave this error: Error    31  Keyword is not valid as an identifier.  C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\POMan\WebApplication1\Global.asax.vb    4   14  C:...\POMan\

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

If you really really want to call it Global, then use [Global], although I would recommend changing the name instead.

If you continue to call it Global, then be aware also that any reference to the class will need to be prefixed with the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name `Global` to be something more descriptive, so that it doesn't clash.